# Matching the content in any of 13 fields in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql

The Retrosheet Events database contains one row for every play in Major League baseball for around the last 100 years.  It currently has about 13 million rows and 163 columns.  13 of these columns contain player identifiers for batter, up to three runners on base and 9 fielders.
I want to write a query which returns, for each player (there are around 22,000 players) the first date in which he appeared.  The following code achieves that for any particular player p:

```
select date
from events
where p in (batter, first_runner, ..., center_field, right_field)
order by date
limit 1
```

Unfortunately, even when I have created an index for all 13 potential matching fields, this takes about 10 seconds, so all 22,000 players will take almost 3 days to run.  Anyone see a way to speed this up at all?

Note: I have many workarounds to the actual problem; I'm really more interested in the SQL problem.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are trying to do.  Can you give a few rows of example data and desired result for that data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can stack this data into a more reasonable schema using the `UNION` operator in a subquery, and then grab your `min(date)` for each player:

```
SELECT player, min(date)
FROM (
  SELECT date, 'batter' as role, batter as player FROM events
  UNION ALL
  SELECT date, 'first_runner', first_runner FROM events
  UNION ALL
  ...continue this logic for remaining 11 roles...
) dt
GROUP BY player;
```

Ultimately it may make sense to change your actual table to this schema since this allows you to add or remove player roles without having to change the schema of the table. It will also make this particular query super fast.

Comment: Thanks.  That's helpful.  I'm definitely not changing the schema to look like this because the question I'm asking is very atypical of what I use the database for, and I have no reason normally to quesry the database in this fashion -- this is pretty much a one-off.  I've tried implementing this but the server in MySQL Workbench is timing out. I'm going to try it with a subset of the database and the changed schema makes sense.  We'll see,

Comment: Well, I managed to run one year in 29 seconds.  That's not super helpful since the data is simply wrong for anyone who made their debut before that year.  But since I have another source for debut year, I think I can make this work.